# Selecting flex items using nth-child inside li tag

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

From the code below, I have 2 li's inside a ul tag. Each of these li's contain 2 divs, both these divs are wrapped in an anchor tag. The anchor tag is the flex container, and the divs's inside are the flex items.

Everything is working nicely, but I'm trying to select `<a>` element in the `<li>` elements that are `:nth-child(even)`. I want to add the following property `flex-direction: row-reverse;` to the anchor.

For whatever reason they are not being picked up, I think this has to do with the fact im wrapping the divs in an anchor tag?

Code Below:

SCSS:

```
.locals {
  li {
     list-style-type: none;

     a.person {
        display:flex;
        text-decoration: none;

        .bg {
            background-position: center center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        & > div:first-child {
            flex: 1;
        }

        & > div:last-child {
            flex: 1;
            padding: 80px 0;

            h2 {
                text-align:center;
                color: $gold;
                font-size:20px;
            }
            p {
                text-align:center;
                color: $gold;
            }
        }
    }
}

 li:nth-child(even) {
     a.person {
         flex-direction: row-reverse;
     }
 }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="locals">
    <li>
        <a class="person" href="">
            <div class="bg" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/350x150'); ">
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2> Test </h2>
                <p> Test </p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="person" href="">
            <div class="bg" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/350x150'); ">
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2> Test </h2>
                <p> Test </p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct the following:

- Add missing `</ul>` closing tag.
- Declare `$gold` variable.

---

**Code Snippet:**  *(Compiled CSS)*

```css
.locals li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.locals li a.person {
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.locals li a.person .bg {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.locals li a.person > div:first-child {
  flex: 1;
}
.locals li a.person > div:last-child {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 80px 0;
}
.locals li a.person > div:last-child h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: gold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.locals li a.person > div:last-child p {
  text-align: center;
  color: gold;
}
.locals li:nth-child(even) a.person {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<ul class="locals">
  <li>
    <a class="person" href="">
      <div class="bg" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/350x150'); ">
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2> Test </h2>
        <p>Test</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="person" href="">
      <div class="bg" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/350x150'); ">
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2> Test </h2>
        <p>Test</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

[**Revised jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/c8rffztn/)

Comment: Many thanks, I have gold declared in a variables .scss file...I was looking way past the closing </ul> tag....lol thank you...Probly best to keep the scss as scss and not go back to standard css.

Comment: @Davabo The compiled CSS was just for illustration purposes :).  You're welcome!